# How can I replicate numpy.roll for sparse matrix without converting it into dense matrix?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, scipy

I am working on some problem which requires rolling the elements in a matrix. Below is the example of using numpy to roll a numpy array as desired. I want to replicate the same for scipy sparse csr_matrix without converting it into dense matrix as in actual use case I am working on would be having very large sparse matrix.

The numpy version:

```
A=np.eye(3,3)
print(np.roll(A,[0,3]))

Outputs:
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

The desired functionality must do something like this:

```
A = np.eye(3, 3)
A = sparse.csr_matrix(A)
print(sparse_roll(A, [0, 3]).todense())

Outputs:
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

where sparse_roll is the function to be implemented.

Comment: `np.roll` works by indexing, e.g. `A[:,[1,2,0]]`.  Try the same with the sparse.